# Is popen standard C function?

Tags: c, unix, process, c-standard-library

Reading about the function [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pclose.3.html).

It is in header `stdio.h` (standard header),
it returns `FILE*` (standard IO struct, unlike Unix functions from `unistd.h`),
but i can't find it on any C standard reference website.

So is it standard, or is it some kind of GCC extension? What is it?

Comment: It is a POSIX standard function, but not a C standard function.

Comment: Then why it's in stdio.h and not in unistd.h or something?

Comment: `popen()` is listed in `<stdio .h>` because it returns a `FILE *` and that type is defined in that header, not `<unistd.h>`.  POSIX adds to a number of the standard C headers.  There’s `fdopen()`, `dprintf()` and (of course) `pclose()` also in `<studio.h>`, and I doubt that list is exhaustive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page you linked:

```
CONFORMING TO         top
       POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008.

       The 'e' value for type is a Linux extension.
```

It a function defined in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) standard. And the `e` value for type is a linux extension.

> Is popen standard C function?

No. `popen` is not a standard C function, meaning it's not defined in [C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html).

> So is it standard, or is it some kind of GCC extension? What is it?

It is a standard POSIX function. It is not a GCC extension. It is a function.

> Then why it's in stdio.h and not in unistd.h or something?

The `popen` declaration is visible after including `stdio.h` on POSIX compatible systems, because the POSIX standard says so. ( Why it's not `posix/stdio.h` or like `sys/stdio.h` it's mostly for historic reasons. Every system just uses `stdio.h`. )